# Mockito & Junit null pointer exception: name must not be null

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I have been trying to run the following test using mockito and junit and I keep on getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: name must not be null"
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

On debugging, I found out that this exception is thrown when the test executes the following statement in isStopValid(String) method:

**FacilityValidationUtil facUtil = new FacilityValidationUtil();**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyFormTest{
    @InjectMocks MyForm form = new MyForm();
    @Mock FacilityValidationUtil facUtil;
    @Test
    public void testIsStopValid() throws FinderException{
        when(facUtil.isFacilityValid("")).thenReturn(false);
        form.setOrigin("");
        assertEquals(false, form.isStopValid(form.getOrigin()));        
    }
}
```

**Class with method to be tested:**

```
public class MyForm{
    FacilityValidationUtil facUtil = new FacilityValidationUtil();
    public boolean isStopValid(String stop){

        try {
            return facUtil.isFacilityValid(stop);
        } catch (FinderException e) {
            log.error("Error finding the stop. "+e.getCause());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FacilityValidationUtil{
    private FacilityDAO facilityDao = new HibernateFacilityDAO();
    public boolean isFacilityValid(String facility) throws FinderException{
        boolean test;
        FacilityImpl facilityImpl = facilityDao.findFacilityByNassCode(facility);
        test = (facilityImpl==null)?false : true;
        return test;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class HibernateFacilityDAO extends HibernateAbstractDeltaDAO implements FacilityDAO {
    public HibernateFacilityDAO() {
        super(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which row in `testIsStopValid()` is causing the exception?

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl assertEquals(false, form.isStopValid(form.getOrigin()));   Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: You are trying to mock a variable (facUtil) that is local to your isStopValid method, so the mock version of this object in your test is never going to be called because you are 'newing it up" each time.

Long Answer: It looks like you are trying to mock the call to your FacilityValidationUtil class, and if this is the case, then you need to either make the class a field so that Mockito can inject the object by reflection (if this object is thread safe, which it looks like it is) or explore a mocking framework like PowerMockito that will allow you to mock a constructor (google for PowerMockito when new).

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(FacilityValidationUtil.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(facUtil);
```

Mockito doesn't support any mocking of constructor args by default.

**EDIT**
If you are still having trouble, then I would suggest starting with a smaller example. I've put together one for you that works and uses the code you are trying to test (It's using inner classes though, which Mockito has some quirky rules about, but I'm just doing it to compress the example).

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyFormTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyForm form = new MyForm();
    @Mock
    private FacilityValidationUtil facUtil;

    @Test
    public void testIsStopValid_false() {
        when(facUtil.isFacilityValid("")).thenReturn(false);
        assertEquals(false, form.isStopValid(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsStopValid_true() {
        when(facUtil.isFacilityValid("")).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(true, form.isStopValid(""));
    }

    public class MyForm {
        private FacilityValidationUtil facUtil = new FacilityValidationUtil();

        public boolean isStopValid(String stop) {
            try {
                return facUtil.isFacilityValid(stop);
            } catch (FinderException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class FacilityValidationUtil {
        public boolean isFacilityValid(String facility) throws FinderException {
            throw new RuntimeException(facility);
        }
    }

    public class FinderException extends RuntimeException {
        public FinderException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

}
```

What's really important is that your mock is not getting injected correctly. Until you get that resolved, you are going to keep getting the same error. Set a break point in your MyForm at the point you call facUtil.isFaciltyValid and look at the object. It should be a mockito object, not your class.

Good luck.

Comment: I made facUtil a class object. I have edited my code above. I still get the same error. The weird thing is, now all my other tests fail with same error.

Comment: I just added some more information for you. You should be able to copy it into a class file and try it out without too much trouble. Let me know if you need more help.